# combobox not refresh on value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

on page init I have following render of combobox element

```
<div class="combobox-container">
    <input type="hidden" name="MySelection" value="">
    <div class="input-group">
       <input class="combobox form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select">
    <ul class="typeahead typeahead-long dropdown-menu">
       <li class="" data-value="val1">
       <li class="active" data-value="val2">
       <li data-value="val3">
       <li data-value="val4">
       <li data-value="val5">
    </ul>
    <span class="input-group-addon dropdown-toggle" data-dropdown="dropdown">
       <span class="caret"></span>
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

which renders combo like

[image]

after I select option from this combo I'm geting rendered like

[image]

now after certain users action I'm resetting combo box on it's default state so I use following code

```
$('#MySelection').val(undefined);
```

this actually change value as I expected but ui elemenent stays intact, it appears 
[image]
and I want to appear as
[image]

I tried with `$('#MySelection').data('combobox').refresh();`
but that doesn't helped.

**Update:**
As someone suggested I tried with moving `$('#MySelection').data('combobox').refresh();`
at the end of the file since I'm getting error inside firebug

> TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined').data('combobox').refresh();

but it doesnt help. I try even to put at the of the `_Layout.cshtml` file after all jquery init files but also without any progress.

Comment: Do you want to empty the data in the select field or refresh it?

Comment: Can you create fiddle with you case? It will be much simplier to help you then.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:** try this:

*bootstrap-combobox:*

```
$('#MySelection').val('');
$('#MySelection').data('combobox','refresh');
```

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.combobox').combobox()

          $("#reset").on("click",function(){
           $('.combobox').val('');
           $('.combobox').data('combobox','refresh');
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/bootstrap-combobox/js/bootstrap-combobox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  
   <link href="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/bootstrap-combobox/css/bootstrap-combobox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
  <body>

        <h1>Vertical Form</h1>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Turns this</label>
            <select class="combobox input-large form-control">
              <option value="">Select a State</option>
              <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
              <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
              <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
              <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
              
            </select>
          </div>
     
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: now I'm getting
TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined').data('combobox').refresh(); inside firebug, and jquery is properly loaded

Comment: @user1765862 This should work if you are calling the refresh at the end.

Comment: see a related thread here:https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/issues/106 it may help.

Comment: examined provided link and tried with piutting $('#MySelection').data('combobox').refresh(); at the end but it doesnt help

Comment: @user1765862 try to fix your html.use `<input type="hidden" name="MySelection"  id="MySelection" value="">`. or does it internally creates id for the given name.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$('#MySelection').val('');
$('#MySelection').data("combobox").clearElement();
$('#MySelection').data('combobox').refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code to set selected index 0

```
$('#MySelection').prop('selectedindex',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your element `<input type="hidden" name="MySelection" value="">`has the name `MySelection`.

With your `$('#MySelection').val(undefined);` you're trying to call it by it's ID (not name).

Try `$('input[name=MySelection]')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I found [@mikeblum's solution](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/issues/168) to work for me.

```
$('#element').data('combobox').clearTarget();
$('#element').data('combobox').clearElement();
```